# adb is not starting when launching android studio

Tags: java, android, ide

When I launch android studio, adb is not shown in task manager, device list in Android Studio stuck on loading, when I press Start device I get the following IDE Internal Error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Unexpected schema version 0
at com.android.dvlib.DeviceSchema.getXsdStream(DeviceSchema.java:262)
at com.android.dvlib.DeviceSchema.getSchema(DeviceSchema.java:346)
at com.android.sdklib.devices.DeviceParser.getParser(DeviceParser.java:537)
at com.android.sdklib.devices.DeviceParser.parseImpl(DeviceParser.java:522)
at com.android.sdklib.devices.DeviceParser.parse(DeviceParser.java:498)
at com.android.sdklib.devices.DeviceManager.initUserDevices(DeviceManager.java:416)
```

I downloaded Java latest version but the problem still persists

[image: Error shown]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue.

The problem was in devices.xml file (located in `C:\Users\<user name>\.android`)

In this line:

```
<d:devices xmlns:d="http://schemas.android.com/sdk/devices/6" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

the number 6 in `http://schemas.android.com/sdk/devices/6` was written in Arabic format.